# the camera background doesn't appear when I run app in the second time.iOS,Vuforia

Tags: ios, camera, appdelegate, vuforia

I do project about Augmented Reality on iOS by using Vuforia for development.

I created the view before start `FrameMarkerAppDelegate` (scan AR View). After I push the `UIButton` on view page, the `FrameMarkerAppDelegate` is started. The background is camera background after `FrameMarkerAppDalegate` run finished. Then I touch the camera background and choose go back view page, now we are on view page again.

My problem is after I push the `UIButton` again, The camera background doesn't appear. It still be view page but the camera is activated.

> ViewController.mm

```
- (IBAction)btnSelect:(id)sender {
    FrameMarkersAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[FrameMarkersAppDelegate alloc] init];
    [appDelegate startFrameAppDelegate];
}
```

> FrameMarkerAppDelegate.mm

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
    [self setupSplashContinuation];
    [QCARutils getInstance].targetType = TYPE_FRAMEMARKERS;
    arParentViewController = [[ARParentViewController alloc] init];
    arParentViewController.arViewRect = screenBounds;
    [window insertSubview:arParentViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



-(void)startFrameAppDelegate
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
    [self setupSplashContinuation];
    [QCARutils getInstance].targetType = TYPE_FRAMEMARKERS;
    arParentViewController = [[ARParentViewController alloc] init];
    arParentViewController.arViewRect = screenBounds;
    [window insertSubview:arParentViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. Basically i think the error is down to merging a non arc vuforia sdk with an arc project. i found when i used the vuforia camera as the opening viewcontroller the 'dealloc' method in the 'ARViewController' wasnt being called when the vuforia viewcontroller ran for the first time. But it would get called everytime after that. Seemed too complicated for me to workout properly so i hacked it by sticking a blankviewcontroller before the 'ImageTargetsParentViewController' pushing the ImageTargetsParentViewController with a method in my navigationcontroller (this method just pushed the ImageTargetsParentViewController viewcontroller). this seemed to fix it and the dealloc now gets called every time.

**blankviewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [((CARNavigationController *)self.navigationController) firstLoadOpenAr];
    });
}
```